# Buscando a próxima tabela após um elemento clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, estou tentando preencher a próxima tabela mais próxima do botão clicado, mas não estou conseguindo.

É importante que seja a próxima logo após, pois existem várias tabelas com a mesma classe, será que podem me ajudar??

Eis o javascript:

```
 $(".btnMostrarCategoria").click(
        function() {

            var nome = $(this).data('nome');

            jQuery("#tabelaUploads tbody").html("");

            console.log($(this).next("table"));

            $.ajax({
              url: "/painel/mostrarUploadsCategorias",
              method: 'POST',
              data: {_token: jQuery(".token").val(), nome: nome},

              success: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                e.forEach(function(item, indice) {
                    //remove o diretório da string e só deixa o nome final do arquivo
                    var nomeArquivo = item.replace('public/painel/categorias/' + nome + "/", ""); 
                    $(this).find('.tabelaUploads tbody').append("<tr><td>" + nomeArquivo + "</td> <td><a class='btn btn-success' href=\"/painel/fazerDownload/" + nome + "/" + nomeArquivo + "\">Download</a> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=\"excluirUpload('" + item + "')\">Excluir</button></td></tr>");
                });
              }
            }).done(function() {        //só abre o modal assim que terminar a requisição ajax
                hidePleaseWait();
            });
        }
    );
```

HTML:

```
@foreach($categorias as $categoria)
                    @if($loop->first)
                      <div class="box"><!-- Usar [.box collapsed-box] nos demais -->
                    @else
                      <div class="box collapsed-box"><!-- Usar [.box collapsed-box] nos demais -->
                    @endif

                      <div class="box-header with-border">

                        <input type="hidden" name="" id="nomeCategoria" value="{{$categoria->nome}}">
                        <h3 class="box-title" data-widget="collapse">{{$categoria->id}}  -  {{ $categoria->nome }}</h3>

                        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool btnMostrarCategoria" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse" data-nome={{ $categoria->nome }}>
                            @if($loop->first)
                              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                            @else
                              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group" id="uploadtr">
                            <input type="hidden" id="idPasta">
                            <br>
                              <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileupload" data-token="{!! csrf_token() !!}" data-pasta="" class="btn btn-primary" multiple ><br/>

                              <div id="progress" class="progress" role="progressbar">
                                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                      <span id="progressValue">0%</span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <span id="mensagemFinalUpload" style="color: #367fa9">Arquivo enviado com sucesso!</span>
                        </div>

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" class="tabelaUploads" data-teste="whatever">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="85%">Arquivo</th>
                                    <th width="15%">Ações</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>

                    </div>
              <!-- /forelse categoria -->
               @endforeach
              <!-- /.box -->
insira o código aqui
```

Comment: Você pode usar o `.parent()` até checar em um elemento que possua tanto o button quanto o table desejados como subelementos. Exemplo: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.table');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, boa noite.

Para conseguir selecionar a tabela mais próxima ao seu botão, eu recomendaria você criar uma div para cada categoria criada, nisso você iria agrupar todos os botões e sua respectiva tabela a essa div, com isso você seria capaz de utilizar o comando [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) disponível na biblioteca [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Fiz um exemplo para que você consiga esclarecer suas dúvidas: https://jsfiddle.net/bh3oj408/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelo exemplo. Funcionou certinho!